Editor does not start from NeoMutt
I have a peculiar problem I cannot solve with the mail-agent NeoMutt:
It cannot start any editor.
When I want to create an email, NeoMutt responds:
sh: 1: vi: Permission denied

I gave the file linked to vi, /usr/bin/vim.basic, all permissions (777) - no effect
I configure NeoMutt with:
set editor='emacs'

And when I try to create an email, it responds:
sh: 1: emacs: not found

Emacs is installed and runs flawlessly from terminal.
I really have no idea what else to try. Any help?
